# Gradle: compile tests but do not run them

Tags: gradle

I would like to run a Gradle build that compiles the tests (JUnit tests in the `src/test/java` directory) but does not run them.

`./gradlew build` compiles and runs the tests, while `./gradlew build -x test` does not compile the tests. I also tried `./gradlew build -x testClasses`, but that does not yield the desired result as it builds and runs the tests.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

TL;DR: `gradle testClasses` compiles the test source code.

---

The tasks for compiling the test source code will not be needed when the `test`-task is excluded. Gradle sees that and won't execute the unneeded tasks.

Here is the task dependency graph, when you exclude something all tasks that arent needed for other tasks will be dropped.
[image: Java Task Graph]
[source Gradle User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#lifecycle_tasks)

So looking at the task dependency graph `testClasses` is the task for compiling the test source code and processing the resources.

You could just add this task to your command,

```
gradle build testClasses -x test
```

Or even better use the `assemble`-task (build the jar) with the `testClasses`-task. With this, you do not have to exclude the tests.

```
gradle assemble testClasses
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are building an **Android** project with gradle:

- to build [local tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/local-tests) without running them:

  ```bash
  ./gradlew \
    compile<Variant1>DebugUnitTestSources \
    compile<Variant1>ReleaseUnitTestSources \
    compile<Variant2>DebugUnitTestSources \
    compile<Variant2>ReleaseUnitTestSources \
    compileDebugUnitTestSources \
    compileReleaseUnitTestSources \
    bundleLibResDebug \
    bundleLibResRelease \
    bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug \
    bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
  ```

  Replace `<Variant1>` & `<Variant2>` by the name of your variants if you use variants.

  The 4 last lines are for libraries you may use.
- to build [instrumented tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests) without running them:

  ```bash
  ./gradlew \
    assembleAndroidTest
  ```